# C# : how to stop timezone offset being added to System.DateTime when inserted into a DateTimeOffset SQL Server column

Tags: c#, sql-server, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

I have some C# code that copies rows from one database and inserts them into another. It does this using a `DataTable` and `SqlBulkCopy`.

When imported into my C# application, the timestamp columns have the data type `System.DateTime` inside the `DataTable` that is inserted into SQL Server. Once `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer()` has executed, timestamp values inside the destination tables have the type `datetimeoffset(6)` and have a timezone offset added to them (... +01:00).

How do I stop this happening? It hasn't always happened, only started happening recently.

**UPDATE:**

The timezone expected is UTC, always, for my purposes. However, I am forced to store this in a datetimeoffset column for business reasons. So I'm expecting +00:00

```
DataTable data = importer.GetDataTable();

using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn)){
   copy.WriteToServer(data);
}
```

Comment: So what timezone *are* you expecting? `datetimeoffset` **always** has a timezone, so if you're asking how do you remove it, the answer is simply *you don't*. If you don't want the time zone, don't use `datetimeoffset`.

Comment: @Larnu checkout my update to the question

Comment: @ScottHannen see my update :)

Comment: So show us the code you are using to `INSERT` the data into the SQL instance.

Comment: This documentation might help. It deals with how `SqlBulkCopy` converts `DateTime` and some settings you can change.

Comment: I (and I think others) read this too fast. The question isn't why `DateTimeOffset` has a time zone, but why `DateTime` is converted to `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: @ScottHannen: One thing to point out: a `DateTimeOffset` always has an *offset*. It doesn't have a *time zone*. They're different things. Two different places may temporarily use the same offset, but still be in different time zones.

Comment: Can you modify the `DataTable` (in memory) to convert all the `DateTime` values to `DateTimeOffset` values?

Comment: Note that it is a very bad idea to rely on any kind of conversion when using `SqlBulkCopy`, because you potentially have to contend with two layers of conversion: once in C# when converting the input type to the .NET type matching the T-SQL type, and then another one in SQL Server when it converts the .NET type to the T-SQL type. Both of these have some nasty corner cases. To prevent surprises, always use an input table (or `IDataRecord` collection) with column types that match the destination exactly, and take care of conversions yourself.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, this was my fix, I missed your comment though :( do you want to post an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DateTime.SpecifyKind() on timestamp columns before inserting them into Sql Server didn't work for me.

I solved this by converting (casting) the `System.DateTime` columns to `DateTimeOffset` with an explicit offset of `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)`. This removed the need for C# to implicitly handle the conversion from `DateTime` to `DbType.DateTimeOffset` which was adding an undesired offset.

EDIT

Reading the comments, @JohnSkeet essentially recommended this but I hadn't read everyone's comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `DateTime` and try to write it to a `DateTimeOffset` C# has to figure out what timezone to use. There are explicit conversion functions that allow you to specify but if you don't it will assume the `DateTime` is in the local timezone (as the majority of the time they are).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset provides several examples on how to convert between the two. Note that `SpecifyKind` doesn't require having a `DateTimeOffset` type.

Comment: The conversion is handled by SqlBulkCopy so I can't utilise these explicit conversion functions :/ I will try changing the way the DataTable is defined to make use of this (change it to use datetimeoffset instead of datetime)

Comment: @TurgidWizard: I think Kind is specified within `DateTime` you might be able to overwrite each `DateTime` by calling `SpecifyKind` and storing the result back into the `DataTable`.

Comment: great suggestion but it doesnt seem to work :( I changed the code that populates the DataTable to check if a column is System.DateTime and if it is then it fills the value using colArray[i] = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DataReader[i], DateTimeKind.Utc)... However, the offset is still added when inserted to sql server

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use `your DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` method, and you will remove the time offset.